# Do neutrinos of any flavor get trapped in black holes?

Tags: particle-physics, black-holes, neutrinos

This question has been bothering me a bit. I know that neutrinos have super small mass and they interact via the weak force. Since they have a non-zero mass, they should be affected by black holes and their paths should be affected by them.

Suppose we have a neutrino of any flavor traveling directly to the coordinates of the singularity of a black hole... or its cross sectional impact includes the black hole coordinate. Basically, its going straight towards a black hole...

Given that a black hole has so much mass and is so dense, it surely must be able to interact with a neutrino, right?

What are the conditions for neutrinos to get trapped in a black hole, or not?

Comment: If they go in the horizon they don't come out. Just the same as anything else.

Comment: Yep, even if they were fully massless, they'd be screwed

Answer (score 8):

Like zakk says, the key here is to not just think the black hole's gravity as a force that affects objects based on their mass, rather as a curvature of space-time. In this sense, everything, regardless of mass, is trapped in a black hole because it warps space-time in such a way that the area inside the horizon is essentially cut off from the universe. Light doesn't even escape--not due to the gravitational force, rather because of the way that space and time don't allow it a way out.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Not even the light, which has no mass, can escape when it goes too near to a black hole, let alone the (tinily) massive neutrinos. Also neutrinos interact via the weak force, as you correctly state, but they also interact via gravitational interaction (even if they were massless they would, obviously when speaking about black holes one has to use General Relativity as opposed to Newtonian Mechanics).

Answer (score -4):

I respectfully disagree with other answers. NASA has detected that the massive black hole at the center of our galaxy produces huge amounts of neutrinos. https://www.nasa.gov/centers/marshall/news/news/releases/2014/14-169.html Therefore it would make no sense that black holes consume them, they would never escape the black hole then.

Comment: Presumably, the neutrinos are produced at the accretion disk. If something, including neutrinos, enters the horizon, it does get trapped in the black hole. These two statements are not contradictory; neutrinos can be produced *and* consumed by black holes.

Comment: They are contradictory. If a black hole produces anything and releases it, what ever they may be, then those particles would be trapped in the event horizon again and dragged back. You seem to think that a black hole has a mouth and an anus, it does not.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my point. The accretion disk is *outside* the event horizon. Therefore, neutrinos produced in the AD can escape. Those produced inside the EH cannot. Both processes are possible.

Comment: Aha, sorry my mistake.

Comment: Maybe it would have been clearer (and more accurate?) if the linked article stated that the accretion disk created the neutrinos..