# Neutrinos and black holes

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, causality, neutrinos, accretion-disk

As a new user I could not comment on [Do neutrinos of any flavor get trapped in black holes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57681/)

My question is that the Ice Cube facility has mapped Neutrinos coming from black holes, as stated in comments on the referenced article once past the EH as they have mass how can this be. Are they coming from outside the EH then from interactions not the BH itself?

Answer (score 6):

Anything we detect "coming from a black hole" is not coming from within the event horizon. Usually radiation or particles are emitted from the accretion disk.

Also, as pointed out in all the answers on the question you linked, the event horizon is a boundary from which *nothing* leaves, not just massive particles. The answers there explain this a bit more.